# A simple website monitoring service with notifications and performance reports

Tags: web-apps, monitoring, notification

I'm using [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) (free version) to monitor one of my sites. All I need is to have instant notifications (any way -- e-mail / SMS / mobile app), when any of my sites goes down, in addition to a simple monthly report on site performance. An optional way to publish this information as a simple graph / site-is-online indicator would be perfect.

Pingdom seemed perfect for this task when I started to use it around year ago. But now it has matured way beyond my expectations. All these alert scenarios, reports, RUMs, users, tabs, switches, etc. are simply an overkill for me and for the task I need it to perform.

Can someone suggest any alternative software or service for simple site monitoring that would offer the things I described and not much more than that? A service that wouldn't be an overkill, which Pingdom has recently become in my opinion.

Comment: https://uptime.onl - build with simplicity in mind

Comment: @KonstantinBogomolov Sounds like a great answer, in addition to all those already posted. Why comment only then...

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that [Bosun](http://bosun.org/), an open-source tool developed by the very own Stack Exchange dev team, cand be the answer to all my needs. It is still in early stage of developement, but it seems to be very promising.

If you're interested, read more details on either [Stack Exchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/announcing-bosun-our-new-open-source-monitoring-alerting-system/?cb=1) or in [Server Fault Blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/2014/11/10/announcing-bosun/).

Comment: Can you elaborate how bosun helps? I've installed it, and on the first glance it allows to monitor a ton of system internals, like cpu usage, memory usage, disk space and so on. That is all not available on shared hosting... Is there a plugin or something that could be used with shared hosting?

Comment: I have only read documentation very briefly. It seems, that your website / application is responsible for pushing simple JSON, which is captured and analyzed by Boson. Therefore, you're in the control of what Boson gets / checks / analyzes. But these are only my asumptions / expectations. I haven't got chance to test Boson myself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've read too, but I thought I might have missed something. So I'd still need to do the actual monitoring, and bosun is only a backend to process the monitoring data, and act on it.

Comment: @Jost: Correct, bosun was actually called "TSAF: Time Series Alerting Framework" while we were first developing it. So what bosun mostly does by itself is alert on time series. scollector gets you a lot of various system and application metrics if you run it as an agent. But you can monitor anything really (For example, you could ask everyone who walks through the door if Narwals are real, and alert if people are losing faith over time.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm representing [SuperMonitoring](http://www.supermonitoring.com/) - an uptime monitoring service powered by Superheroes. ;)
I think you might like it, because the interface is simple and more advanced features are not turned on by default.

Comment: As OP, thank you for your answer. As customer, however, I must admit, that your site graphic kills, but offer isn't that killing after all. For 15 bucks monthly [you offer](http://www.supermonitoring.com/p/pricing) **three** IPs, tested by network of _four_ stations, where Pingdom for the same price [offers](https://www.pingdom.com/pricing/) **ten** IPs, tested by a network of _fifty_ stations around the globe.

Answer (score 1):

[Pingometer](http://alternativeto.net/software/pingometer/) can check if your site is up once a minute in the free plan, and it's very basic.

BTW, Alternativeto.net is a great way to find serices similar to a given one.

Answer (score 1):

[UpTime.onl](https://uptime.onl/) - built with simplicity in mind

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, could be a [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/), which comes with a [free plan](https://www.datadoghq.com/pricing/) for up to five hosts.

The good question is, what does it mean, that free plan does not have "*Metric alerts*"? Does it mean, that you can only monitor hosts manually, buy will never get any kind of alert, when something goes down?